# "The roar of a lion" : Why do we use the definite article "the"?

Tags: articles, definite-article, indefinite-article, grammaticality-in-context, generic-noun-phrases

> "The roar of a lion can reach 114 decibels at a distance of 1 metre, and can be heard from 8 kilometers (5 miles) away."

Why do we need the definite article here instead of the indefinite counterpart "a" in this sentence?

As a matter of fact, a lion can roar countless times during its lifetime so there can be more than just one roar.

Comment: You don't *need* a definite article there. You could use an indefinite article. See http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/000001.html

Answer (score 1):

Because it is not just "a roar" (which means something like "any roar") but a *specific* roar - **that of a lion**, as opposed to the roar of a leopard, bear, a red deer, etc.

Reference:  [Indefinite vs Definite Articles](https://www.englishpage.com/articles/a-an-vs-the.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The scientific facts or established characters of in/animated objects would take the definite article. Why? Because they are the facts. True that a lion roars countless times but we are talking about 'the roaring' in general, as a personal character.

This may go true for all the facts. Say *"The voice of a woman is thinner as compared to a man;" "The shape of a pizza is round."* And, so on!

Comment: In this context, the roar of a lion = the ability to roar of a lion ?

Comment: @cpp_noname no... the 'natural roaring.' By calling it 'ability' you indirectly mean their efforts. I am talking about the natural feature/characteristic of lion. *The computing speed of a computer is very fast!* That way...

Comment: The voice of a woman is *thinner* than that of a man? *Thinner?*

Comment: @Clare what's wrong in 'thinner?'

Comment: Why was this answer down-voted?